Reading Chinese characters from a foreign table (MariaDB) in a PSQL database
I have a PSQL database that has to read data from a MariaDB database.
The MariaDB table is encoded in utf8_general_ci and PSQL database is in UTF8.
When I write Chinese characters from either side they show up incorrectly encoded on the other.
Does anyone know how I can fix this from the PSQL side? Thanks
I tried setting the collation when creating the foreign table in PSQL but no luck.

What's the exact version of mysql? In older versions of mysql utf8 was encoded in 3 bytes only, you needed to use utf8mb4 character set for proper utf8

Just realized the mysql database is in fact 5.5.65-MariaDB. Will do some more searching, thanks for the vital tip.

Mariadb is NOT mysql!

https://web.archive.org/web/20160412122414/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html  though that says "For a supplementary character, utf8 cannot store the character at all, whereas utf8mb4 requires four bytes to store it. Because utf8 cannot store the character at all, you have no supplementary characters in utf8 columns and need not worry about converting characters or losing data when upgrading utf8 data from older versions of MySQL." which may not be true if your client has been successfully storing and reading Chinese, albeit storing it in an unsupported way

note that mysql and mariadb 5.5 are both long past end of life and no longer receiving security updates; consider them insecure and upgrade as soon as possible (to the latest stable mariadb 11.3 or long term support versions 10.6 or 10.11)

@Shadow now, yes, but mariadb 5.5 is pretty close to mysql 5.5 but with a few things from mysql 5.7

@ysth pretty close is not same. Can you confirm with absolute certainty that mariadb does not behave differently when handling utf8 characters from mysql? I had several questions here on SO, when I could not reproduce the problem just to find out that the OP was using mariadb and not mysql.

Some of Chinese (and some of Emoji) needs CHARACTER SET utf8mb4, not just utf8 (aka utf8mb3).
utf8mb4 was available in MySQL 5.5 and MariaDB 5.5 and all subsequent versions.  (5.5 had some INDEX definition issues, but there are workarounds.)
Do this to each table:
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;

But be cautious; several things can go wrong, and you may need to take a different approach to conversion.
Meanwhile, the 4-byte Chinese characters already stored in tables will be trashed, and cannot be recovered.
